# Apache Camel corba external connections fail under some Linux paths

Tags: java, linux, apache-camel, corba

I am using Apache Camel to connect to an external Corba name service. The system does have STIGs (Security Technical Implementation Guide) applied, SELinux and firewall policies in place. I can successfully connect to the Corba name service but only under some folders on the Linux machine. For instance, if I deploy my camel application under my home directory or /tmp it connects fine, but when I try under /opt or /usr it fails to connect. Also, if I make a copy of the /opt folder to /opts it connects fine.  I've tried adjusting the SELinux labels, as well as disabling SELinux and iptables but the connection still fails under those folders.

I am using OpenJDK 11 for my application but it is just the default installation without any security measures in place yet.

Any ideas or things I can look at that may be causing this odd behavior with external corba connections under specific paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was a class loader problem related to two different jars having identical classes and which classes got loaded first based on the path.  Removing the unneeded jar fixed the issue.